# How to statistics G1 mixed gc count

Tags: jvm, garbage-collection, g1gc

I use jstat -gc command to view gc count,But I don't know which indicator represents mixed gc count.

jdk verson is 17.0.9,garbage collector is G1.

```
jstat -gc -t 3571192 1000 1000
Timestamp           S0C         S1C         S0U         S1U          EC           EU           OC           OU          MC         MU       CCSC      CCSU     YGC     YGCT     FGC    FGCT     CGC    CGCT       GCT
       353547.0         0.0      1024.0         0.0       561.3     146432.0      26624.0     136192.0      81438.0   127296.0   125686.7   15616.0   14632.4  12235   112.137     0     0.000  7870   100.747   212.884
       353548.0         0.0      1024.0         0.0       561.3     146432.0      26624.0     136192.0      81438.0   127296.0   125686.7   15616.0   14632.4  12235   112.137     0     0.000  7870   100.747   212.884
```

I want to know which indicator represents the count of mixed GC, or what tool can be used to see the count of mixed GC.